# Missing "Add new data source" and "Show data sources" option in web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Windows application project.  I could go to the menu `Data > Add new data source` and successfully added a new data source of customers table from northwind database.

I could also drag and drop customers table from data sources window to a Windows form.

I want to perform SAME action with a web form.

I created an empty website (tried also with web project) and tried to perform similar activity.

There is not `Add new data source` or `Show data sources` options here.

How can the same be done in a web forms application?

Comment: Greetings Aditya Bokade.  Just a helpful tip to encourage answers, there are some answers to some of your previous questions that should probably be flagged as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Add a grid view or some other explicit data control and you will have the option to configure that.  Also, you can define your data sources in web.config.  Web development is a different world.  Some things are necessarily different.

Comment: I added a gridview on this default.aspx as you directed. But it did not help. I am trying this only because it is mentioned to do in pro asp.net book from appress.

Comment: Well, tell us exactly what you are trying to do, and we can get you the help you need.  If you are a winforms guy, webforms is definitely going to stretch you out of your comfort zone, as there is much learn.

Comment: Its the same thing I want to try. I already have learnt most of the webforms. And I was just trying whether drag/drop table from data source works on webforms or not. Because its mentioned in pro asp of appress. I know how to create sqlDataSource and store table in it and then how to bind it to gridview. Thanks for your concern, GrayFox!

Comment: The ASP.NET Step by Step by Microsoft Press http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-ASP-NET-Step/dp/0735627010/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340411514&sr=8-1&keywords=asp.net+step+by+step

Comment: This doesn't help sometimes you want your datasouce to be a class object which already exists within the project.